# How to update all columns of a row at once using spreadsheet on Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I read some other similar questions but I couldn't understand it how to do it on my code.

I have a spreadsheet that will be filled with an app, I am using appendRow to add rows but now I need to update the entire row with new array of data, if the variable pid(Código) from the row I am receiving exists on the spreadsheet, I need to update it, not add a new row.

[image: My Spreadsheet]

```
    function doGet(request) {


      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");

      var data = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

      var updateIndex;


      try{

        var pid = request.parameter.pid;
        var nome = request.parameter.nome;
        var desc = request.parameter.desc;
        var marca = request.parameter.marca;
        var tipo = request.parameter.tipo;
        var preco = request.parameter.preco;
        var ativado = request.parameter.ativado;

        var rowData = [pid, nome, desc, marca, tipo, preco, ativado];

         // loop through all rows to check the column "pid" has the value of variable "pid"

          for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){

            if(data[i][0] == pid){
              updateIndex = i;
            }


          }

      // Update the row here with "rowData"? 
      sheet.



  } catch(e){

    console.log(e);

  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doGet(request) {
      var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");
      var data=sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
      var updateIndex;
      try{
        var pid=request.parameter.pid;
        var nome=request.parameter.nome;
        var desc=request.parameter.desc;
        var marca=request.parameter.marca;
        var tipo=request.parameter.tipo;
        var preco=request.parameter.preco;
        var ativado=request.parameter.ativado;
        var rowData=[pid, nome, desc, marca, tipo, preco, ativado];
          for(var i=1; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i][0] == pid){
              updateIndex=i;
              break;
            }
          }
         sheet.getRange(updateIndex+1,1,1,rowData.length).setValues([rowData]);
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType);
}
```

[Sheet.getRange(start row,start col,number of rows,number of columns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: Could you please explain me these parameters inside getRange()?

Comment: It's all explained in the reference I just added.

Comment: Using your code I get this exception: "Exception: The parameters (String, number, number, number) do not match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange." Looks like the first parameter is a String, that's strange.

Comment: Even if I pass a String I have the same exception: sheet.getRange(updateIndex.toString(),1,1,rowData.length).setValues(rowData);

Comment: I solved the problem and I will accept your answer, the thing was that Spreadsheet class has getRange(String, number, number, number), what I was looking for is getRange from Sheet class (number, number, number, number) so: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); it's working now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- When `pid` is included in the values of the column "A", you want to replace the row with `rowData`.
- When `pid` is NOT included in the values of the column "A", you want to append new row with `rowData`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function doGet(request) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID");
  var range = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();  // Added
  var data = range.getValues();  // Modified
  var updateIndex = 0;  // Modified
  try{
    var pid = request.parameter.pid;
    var nome = request.parameter.nome;
    var desc = request.parameter.desc;
    var marca = request.parameter.marca;
    var tipo = request.parameter.tipo;
    var preco = request.parameter.preco;
    var ativado = request.parameter.ativado;
    var rowData = [pid, nome, desc, marca, tipo, preco, ativado];
    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
      if(data[i][0] == pid){
        data[i] = rowData;  // Added
        updateIndex = i;
      }
    }
    if (updateIndex != 0) {  // Added
      range.setValues(data);
    } else {
      sheet.appendRow(rowData);
    }
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  // In your script, "result" is not declared. Please be careful this.
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `result` is not declared. Please be careful this.
- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. So please be careful this.**

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: No, when the user edits the data from some data from a product on my app the app will send the data (rowData) to the Google Spreedsheet, then the script will receive the data, check if some row has the "pid" (product id), and instead of adding a new row with the rowData I need to update the same row if pid exists on the spreadsheet. If you could edit your answer that will be great :)

Comment: About the result, I forgot to add, but on the original code it's there.

Comment: @djalmafreestyler Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. At first, I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct. From your replying, you want to overwrite the existing row when `pid` is included in the column "A" of the Spreadsheet. On the other hand, when `pid` is NOT included in the column "A", you don't want to append `rowData`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks you very much for replying, I apologize for my english. Ok I'll try to explain each step. I think I will need to explain where the data come from to make you understand my complicated code hehe, ok, first I the user will add register products to the app, each product will be added in an row (with those columns , pid, nome etc), second the data will be received and add to the the spreadsheet, for example we have pid = 1, if the user opens product 1 on the app and update some data...

Comment: When the script receives the data (row with those colums) it should check if the pid exists on the spreadsheet, if so, update the current row pid = 1, not add a new one with the same values, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @djalmafreestyler Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, how about removing `sheet.appendRow(rowData);` from my modified script? Is this the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function doGet(request) {

      // Modified
      var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById("DOCUMENT_ID").getActiveSheet();          
      var data=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      // 

      var updateIndex;
      try{
        var pid=request.parameter.pid;
        var nome=request.parameter.nome;
        var desc=request.parameter.desc;
        var marca=request.parameter.marca;
        var tipo=request.parameter.tipo;
        var preco=request.parameter.preco;
        var ativado=request.parameter.ativado;
        var rowData=[pid, nome, desc, marca, tipo, preco, ativado];
          for(var i=1; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i][0] == pid){
              updateIndex=i;
              break;
            }
          }

         // Modifed
         sheet.getRange(updateIndex + 1, 1, 1, rowData.length).setValues( [rowData] );
         //

  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType);
}
```

Comment: Welcom to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Same error I had with Cooper's code: "Exception: The parameters (String, number, number, number) do not match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange." It seems to be the getRange method, first parameter is asking for a String...